# Exporting mysql table to csv

Tags: mysql, csv, export, sqlyog

I am using sqlyog and trying to export the data of a table to csv. The settings I use for exporting are:

- Escaped by: \
- Lines terminated by: \r\n
- Variable length: Fields terminated by: ,  ,Fields enclosed by: " Optionally

The problem is that some of my fields contain data with ", e.g. The place of the meeting is at "Plaza hotel". This "corrupts" the data and the fields are not shown as they should be. Is there a way I can fix this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Refer MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html#character-escape-sequences

> A “"” inside a string quoted with “"” may be written as “""”.

So use Double-quotes as "Escape Character".

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a query like:

```
SELECT name, email, age
FROM
users
WHERE status = 'Active';
```

So if we need to export this data into a csv file then using below query we can do:

```
SELECT name, email, age
FROM
users
WHERE status = 'Active'
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/xampp/users.csv'
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ';' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```